# How do a I get a bit.ly to point to a https URL?

Tags: https, bit.ly

I have a bit.ly account, with a customized short URL.
However, I want to turn off http and turn on https.
I can't figure out how to get bit.ly to point to a HTTPS URL.
Is there a way? Thanks.

Comment: Once a bitly link is created, the target URL can't be changed. You could create a new bitly link pointing to the HTTPS version.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment on whether HTTPS can be used with customized URLs, but bit.ly does support HTTPS target URLs to some extent because the following link works:

http://bit.ly/tT1Ms maps to https://test.com

Answer (score 0):

Bit.ly only stores the part of the URL that follows the "http://" or "https://" prefix. Unfortunately that means you can't specify one or the other. The protocol will be determined by the website you're connecting to. Sorry!